# Не выполнять скрипт, если переданная информация меньше 2-х символов - как? PHP.

Tags: php

Каким образом можно запретить выполнение скрипта, если переданная post запросом информация по длине меньше 2-х символов?

Comment: В какой-то определённой переменной, или вообще?

Comment: В какой-то определенной переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strlen($_POST['название поля'])>2)что-то делаем.
Если надо только список параметров - лучше воспользоваться in_array()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
if( $_POST['someImportantValue'] && mb_strlen( $_POST['someImportantValue'] ) > 2 ) {
    // все путем, выполняем скрипт
}
```